# show "disclaimer" on the bottom of screen, but print only on the first page

Tags: html, css

I am not a web developer, but put in position to generate a static HTML report page.

The page needs to have a 'Disclaimer' at the bottom of the screen when show in the borrower; but print on the bottom of the first page only.

I use 'fixed' position. it seems locking the 'footer' at the bottom of the screen fine:

```
#footer{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  clear: both;
}
```

But with two problems:

1. it prints on every page
2. it blocks the content (both on screen and in print)

Please help me solving this, or point me to right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: `@media` tags might be what you're looking for: use different styles with `@media screen` and `@media print`

Answer (score 0):

OP did not say he is using any CMS, so I am assuming he is writing HTML code from scratch. To answer your question:

### 1. it prints on every page

I would suggest using media query. Apply two different css rules depending on whehter the page is on browser (screen) or in print (print) There are two cases of footer you have here.

1. On front page, display footer no matter what.
2. On every other page, display footer in browser(screen) mode.

For the first one, make a footer element with id="footer" just as before:

```
<div id="footer"> This is my disclaimer. </div>
```

Then in css, apply your styling just as before:

```
#footer{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  clear: both;
}
```

This way, the front page would have the footer no matter what. Then, on every other page, use a same id but add a class="hideOnPrint" like so:

```
<div id="footerOtherPage" class="hideOnPrint"> This is my disclaimer. </div>
```

And in your css, apply media query to hide this element in print:

```
@media print{

    .hideOnPrint{
       display: hide;
    }

}
```

This way, only when the page is viewed in print, the style on .hideOnPrint would take effect. Learn more about media query [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).

### 2. it blocks the content (both on screen and in print)

This has to do with the position styling you used.

```
position: fixed;
```

Fixed means that element is stuck with respect to the browser window. Like those sticky header you see sometimes at other website. The footer is displayed at the bottom regardless of whether it is block the underlying content.

To solve this: just remove that position css styling. Or just set it to relative. To learn more about position, check out this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).